# Bind Value From XMLWebService to Dropdownlist in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web-services, drop-down-menu

How to bind data from an XMLWebService to a DropDownList?

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
Dim xMaster As New MasterService.Masterservice

DT = xMaster.GetDataProgram
DT.Load(DT)

DDL.DataSource = DT
DDL.DataTextField = DT.Columns("cdProgram").ColumnName.ToString()
DDL.DataValueField = DT.Columns("nmProgram").ColumnName.ToString()
DDL.DataBind()
```

I tried to bind it to the GridView and the values are shown.  But, when I tried to bind it to the dropdownlist, it returns nothing.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DDL.DataTextField = "cdProgram"
DDL.DataValueField = "nmProgram"
```